# jqGrid not rendered when the html page containing the grid is loaded through an ajax call

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a html page ( editor.php ) which contains a lot of html pages in the form of jquery tabs. Each tab is loaded through ajax.

One of the tab ( oven.php ) has a jqgrid built inside. When i load oven.php through ajax call like below

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "oven.php",
            data: "method=" +method+"&mode="+mode,
            cache: false,
            async: true, 
            success: function(data){    
               htdata = data;      
               $("#oven").html(data);   

            },
            });
```

When i do the above the editor.php page doesn't show the grid from oven.php. However if see oven.php page separately, i am able to view the jqgrid.

The grid page is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Oven</title>
<link type="text/css" href="../../css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./jquery/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./jquery/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="./jquery/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true; 
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true; 
    var lastSelection; 
    </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/grid.base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/grid.common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/grid.formedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/grid.inlinedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/grid.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/jquery.searchFilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/src/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">

function() {



     var lastsel2 =
jQuery("#tempset").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 260,
    width:300,
       colNames:[ ' ','Rate *C/Min','Value *C', 'Hold Time min', 'Run Time min'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
           {name:'rate',index:'rate', width:40,editable: true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
           {name:'value',index:'value', width:40, editable: true,editoptions: {size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
           {name:'holdtime',index:'holdtime', width:50, editable: true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},        
           {name:'runtime',index:'runtime', width:100,editable: false}        
       ],
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel2){
            jQuery('#tempset').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
            jQuery('#tempset').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
            lastsel2=id;
        }
    },
    //editurl: "server.php",
    caption: "Temperature Settings",
    pager: "#tempset_pager",
});
var mydata2 = [
        {id:"initial",rate:"",value:"50",holdtime:"60",runtime:"60"},
        {id:"Ramp 1",rate:"15",value:"67 ",holdtime:"5",runtime:"66.133"},
        {id:"Ramp 2",rate:"20",value:"89",holdtime:"10",runtime:"77.233"},
        {id:"Ramp 3",rate:"25",value:"123",holdtime:"3",runtime:"81.593"}
        ];

for(var i=0;i < mydata2.length;i++)
{
//alert(mydata2[i].id);
 jQuery("#tempset").jqGrid('addRowData',mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
 }

 jQuery("#tempset").navGrid("#tempset_pager", {});

 }



</script>
</head>

<body>
<
<div style = "margin-left:240px; top: 15px; position:absolute;">
 <table id="tempset"></table>
        <div id="tempset_pager"> </div>
 </div>



<script>


grid();


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how the `$.ajax` method with `$("#oven").html(data)` inside of `success` work. In the way you **can't load just new HTML page** as per setting new value for `windows.location`. If you load the page per `$.ajax` no scripts will be run at least because of [the security reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Moreover you can't just set the *whole* HTML page inclusive `<html>`, `<head>` `<body>` and so on inside on another part of HTML page. So with respect of `$.ajax` method **you can only load a HTML fragment and not the whole HTML page**.

So you should redesign your program and not use `$.ajax` in such way.

Another remark. If you even seen something if you load `oven.php` **the page have many errors**. Here are only the most important:

- Your page have to start with `<!DOCUMENT html ...>` statement. Without the statement you have HTML page in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) which is not supported by jQuery UI or jqGrid. You have to include the line like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file)) or HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- You can't include the same implementation of the same functions or objects more as one time. You code first include `jquery-1.6.2.min.js`, then `jquery-1.4.2.min.js`. It's heavy error. You include jqGrid code **3 times (!!!???)**. See `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`, then `grid.base.js` till `grid.jqueryui.js` and then one more time `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. You can't do this!

The rest code which define jqGrid contain some errors and some not optimal code (very old style of code).

- you should replace the line `var lastsel2 =` to `var lastsel2;`, which should just define `lastsel2` with `undefined` value.
- the usage of `addRowData` *after* the grid definition is not good. It's very old style. Much better will be to move the definition of `mydata2` before the jqGrid creation and use additional parameters `data: mydata2` and `gridview: true` in the grid.

Comment: Hi ,  Thanks for the detailed response.I kind of understood what you said.   I have designed the pages in such a way that the main page has elements that serves as placeholders for html pages that will be requested using ajax. I guess this is a bad idea since everytime i need to load a new method, i am requesting the html again and again with values filled in its own DOm structure which is  waste. According to your suggestion, I should build the main pages to all the pages in itself as elements and then request only the data from server and insert.

Comment: @srini: the HTML markup for jqGrid is already prepared for `$.ajax`: `<table id="tempset"></table><div id="tempset_pager"></div>` will display nothing till you call `jQuery("#tempset").jqGrid({...});`. So you should load all JavaScrip file *on the main page*. If you would use some kind of "master pages" you can make the grid very flexible. You can include the main code on all paged in "master pages" and load the specific code which define real grid from `<table id="tempset"></table><div id="tempset_pager"></div>` on every individual page. You can create many other scenarios which will work.